# Choose an existing theme in QIcon::setFallbackThemeName() without a QGuiApplication instance

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

My Qt5 app in python does use a lot of icons but sometimes an icon cannot be loaded from the current theme (not every theme implements every icon specified in the [freedesktop spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html)) so I use
code like this:

```
# https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
my_icon = QIcon.fromTheme('document-save')
if my_icon.isNull():
    # use a fallback item
```

I would like to use [`QIcon.setFallbackThemeName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#setFallbackThemeName) now to specify
another installed "fallback" theme to load icons missing in the primary theme
but the doc says

> ... this should be done before creating QGuiApplication, to ensure correct initialization.

How can I choose another installed theme (not the active one) because to find out the active theme I need to create a `QGuiApplication` instance and call `.style().objectName()`:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
active_style = app.style().objectName()
available_styles = QStyleFactory.keys()
fallback_theme = ...  # choose another theme than the active one
QIcon.setFallbackThemeName(fallback_theme)  # this is not recommended (see above cited doc)
```

PS: I know I could destroy and recreate the `app` as workaround but this just adds startup-time

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to access the style: icon themes and styles are not necessarily related (the fact that they might have similar names is irrelevant). Note that, if you're using Linux, Qt always returns the system default icon theme, but there is no certainty that that theme has all icons. A possibility is to look up for all icon search paths (`QStandardPaths.locateAll(QStandardPaths.GenericDataLocation, 'icons', QStandardPaths.LocateDirectory)), browse through each of them, and finally add the folders containing possible icon files (png, xpm and svg).

Comment: For obvious reasons, that would possibly make the startup time terribly long, especially if the user has lots of installed themes and those themes have lots of icons. An alternate solution could be to overwrite the static `fromTheme()` with a custom function that would always check if the icon `isNull()` and eventually browse all available theme paths (as written above) until a proper icon is found, possibly by using a global cache dict to improve performance.

Comment: Looking up every icon file in all search paths would take too long IMHO and I prefer using [`QIcon.fromTheme(const QString &name, const QIcon &fallback)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme-1) to specify a Qt5 built-in icon as fallback which a) obviously is neither possible for all icons a theme may offer and b) does break the look & feel of the active theme. So I want to use `QIcon.setFallbackThemeName()` to double my chance of getting a themed icon (and only otherwise fall back to Qt5 built-in icons).

Comment: The fact is that even if you set a fallback search theme, there's no easy way to tell if that theme contains "more" icons. The user may have lots of themes (for instance, I have 20 icon themes installed on my system), how would you choose one? In any case, you can get a list of parent folders that could possibly contain icon themes using [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html): `QStandardPaths.locateAll(QStandardPaths.GenericDataLocation, 'icons', QStandardPaths.LocateDirectory)`