# Qt5 standard icons available as resource file?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5

I can get a standard icon via this code (using `PyQt5`)

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
default_icon = qApp.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DialogSaveButton)
```

and use it as fallback icon in

```
my_icon = QIcon.fromTheme('document-save', default_icon)
```

Are these standard icons also available as resource file so that I can load
them without a `QApplication` instance?

PS: See also: [Choose an existing theme in QIcon::setFallbackThemeName() without a QGuiApplication instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74496617)

Comment: No, they are not, at least not directly: 1. both QStyle and QIcon are only available as soon as a QApplication instance exists; 2. each QStyle might have its own way of providing icons, and they usually base their behavior on aspects that only a QApplication could provide. Even if they might not actually need a QApplication, they usually do need at least a QCoreApplication (or QGuiApplication).

Comment: There's little point in using both `standardIcon` *and* `fromTheme`, since the former will in most cases call the latter first anyway (before falling back on other resources). You could of course use hackery to load the embedded resources directly via `QFile`, but the path names are entirely implementation specific and could change at any time. Really, it's up to the user to ensure their system has all the standard icons installed (e.g. using a local hicolor theme, if necessary), and applications should avoid attempting to interfere with that.